# angular element unit testing .valid returns false

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have the following input element in an angular form

```
<input type="text" 
                                    id="description" name="description" [value]="description"
                                    [(ngModel)]="description" (change)="update(description)"
                                    #description="ngModel" maxlength="100" required/>
```

Now my problem is that when in actual development in the `update` method `update(elementRef: any)` when I check `elementRef.valid` it returns true, however in unit testing when I check the same it returns `false`, I`m not sure what is going wrong here.

On further investigation I found out that if I removed `required` then it passes the validation on the unit test.

Comment: can u post the unit test code ?

Comment: this is what my code looks like

const descInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#css-selector'));
        descInput.triggerEventHandler('focus', null);
        descInput.triggerEventHandler('change', null);

        expect(updateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            'description': 'mock',
            'iD_Catalogue': 1
        });

sorry if its a bit all in one line.